# PACT error while loading pact_helper.rb (Malformed version number string )

Tags: ruby, pact

When I run the pact test, I get the following error.

> An error occurred while loading ./spec/mailers/mailing_spec.rb.
>
> Failure/Error:
>    mock_service :core_service do
>          port "3003"
>    end
>
> ArgumentError:
>      Malformed version number string

Any ideas around this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please raise an issue in the [pact-ruby](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby) and include all the relevant versions, and the steps to recreate the issue, preferably with an executable code example.